# Why does Captcha appear on contact form 7 only when user is logged into wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have Contact Form 7 version 3.6, and Really Simple CAPTCHA version 1.7 installed with Wordpress 3.8

Everything used to work fine before upgrading to Wordpress 3.8.
Now after upgrading to Wordpress 3.8, instead of displaying the captcha image on my contact form, I see just text saying "Captcha".

If I log into my wp-admin account, and visit the same contact page again, I the captcha image displays as it should.

What is the problem? What code change do I need to make to get it to display correctly?

EDIT: I just edited the contact form - I removed the captchac and captchar tags. When I refreshed the page, the page does't show the captcha prompt anymore. But After logging out, If I visit my contact page, I still see the broken captcha I say earlier (captcha text, instead of the actual captcha image). It seems the users who are logged in do not see the current page, but some old broken page. how do i fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No I didn't. I had to disable the captcha otherwise one couldn't use the form. If you find out, please answer here.

Comment: I didn't change anything, and it suddenly started to work. No idea of cause =/ sorry.

Comment: Do you have wordpress or your other plugins to auto update or something ?

Comment: I think wordpress after a version (can't remember which) auto updates minor versions, but no plugins were set to auto update.